# getting the height from the width value through css

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to get width value in px which is in percentage and apply to that another element?

### first of all take a look at my code

```
<div class="col-md-6 height-half">
     .........
</div>
```

`col-md-6` means its width is 50%;its not in pixel.And the added `height-half` means i want to apply `max-height` half of the width.

### Can i do that only with css?

### *This portion is not important just for posting question*

So i also can do some more works done with that.Such like height-one-fourth,height-one-third and something like that

Comment: You can not use variables in CSS. You would need to use LESS or SCSS

Comment: can i use less with bootstrap?

Comment: You can. Google "Can I use less with bootstrap?"

Comment: http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I might be understanding incorrectly.  But try using the `:before` pseudo element to dictate the height.

You already have the width taken care of with `.col-md-6`.  So with using `:before` on `.height-half` you should be all set:

```
.height-half:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:50%;
}
```

This will make your div have a height equal to 50% of your width.  The only caveat is that you will need to make a container div that is positioned absolutely inside of this div:

```
<div class="col-md-6 height-half">
    <div class="container">
        .........
    </div>
</div>
```

So the CSS has to do this for all of the containers you want to use this way:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

You also need to make all of your columns `position:relative` or some kind of position so that the container sees that it's being positioned absolutely to it's container.

[Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r92fr6rx/)

Comment: i am actually using bootstrap.here container is `position:relative` . so how can i use them??

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam Just use any other word than container.  it could be `.box` doesn't matter much